# Making Environment Changes Stick in Ruby Scripting

Tags: ruby, scripting

Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if __FILE__ == $0
    `cd ..` 
    puts `ls` 
end
```

which runs fine, but when it exits, I'm back where I started. How can I "export" the changes I've made to the environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because the backtick operator is not intended for complicated
scripting. It is useful for running a *single* command (and capturing
its output). There is no shell behind it to store environment changes
*between* its calls and *after* your Ruby script is terminated.

On Linux systems each process has its own current directory path (it
could be found in `/proc/‹pid›/cwd`). Changing directory in a process
does not affect parent processes (the shell you run program from). If
the `cd` built-in were a binary, it could change only its own current
directory, not the one of the parent process, and that is why the `cd`
command could be built-in only.

---

### An alternative implementation

If a Ruby script must be executed from shell and must affect the
shell’s current directory path, the following trick may be used.
Instead of running commands from within Ruby, print those commands to
the standard output, and then `source` it to the shell you are running
the Ruby script from. The commands will *not* be executed by a separate
process of a shell, so all `cd`s *will* take effect in the current
shell instance.

So, instead of

```
ruby run_commands.rb
```

write in your shell-script something like that:

```
source <(ruby prepare_and_print_commands.rb)
```

---

### The `Shell` class

But there is a convenient tool for command line scripting in Ruby: the
[`Shell`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Shell.html) class! It has predefined shortenings for frequently used
commands (such as `cd`, `pwd`, `cat`, `echo`, etc.) and allows to
define your own (it supports *commands* and *aliases*). It also
transparently supports redirection of the standard input and output
streams using `|`, `>`, `<`, `>>`, `<<` Ruby operators.

Working with `Shell` is self-explanatory most of the time. Take a look
at the following straightforward examples.

#### Creating a `Shell` object and changing the current directory

```
sh = Shell.new
sh.cd '~/tmp'
# or
sh = Shell.cd('~/tmp')
```

#### Working within the current directory

```
puts "Working directory: #{sh.pwd}"
(sh.echo 'test') | (sh.tee 'test') > STDOUT
# Redirecting possible to "left" as well as to "right".
(sh.cat < 'test') > 'triple_test'
# '>>' and '<<' are also supported.
sh.cat('test', 'test') >> 'triple_test'
```

Note that parentheses are necessary sometimes because of the
precedence of the redirection operators. Further, the output
of a command is not printed to by default, so you need to specify
that use `> STDOUT`, or `> STDERR` if needed.

#### Testing file properties

```
puts sh.test('e', 'test')
# or
puts sh[:e, 'test']
puts sh[:exists?, 'test']
puts sh[:exists?, 'nonexistent']
```

Works similar to `test` function in a usual shell.

#### Defining custom commands and aliases

```
#                        name    command line to execute
Shell.def_system_command 'list', 'ls -1'

#                   name   cmd   command's arguments
Shell.alias_command "lsC", "ls", "-CBF"
Shell.alias_command("lsC", "ls") { |*opts| ["-CBF", *opts] }
```

The name of a defined command can be used to run it later (in exactly
the same way as it works with predefined `echo` or `cat`, for example).

#### Using the directory stack

```
sh.pushd '/tmp'
sh.list > STDOUT
(sh.echo sh.pwd) > STDOUT
sh.popd
sh.list > STDOUT
(sh.echo sh.pwd) > STDOUT
```

Here the custom `list` command defined above is used.

By the way, there is a convenient `chdir` command to run several
commands in a directory and return to previous working directory
after that.

```
puts sh.pwd
sh.chdir('/tmp') do
    puts sh.pwd
end
puts sh.pwd
```

#### Skip the shell object for a group of commands

```
# Code above, rewritten to drop out 'sh.' in front of each command.
sh.transact do
    pushd '/tmp'
    list > STDOUT
    (echo pwd) > STDOUT
    popd
    list > STDOUT
    (echo pwd) > STDOUT
end
```

#### Additional features

In addition, the `Shell` class has:

- the `foreach` method to iterate through lines in a file, or through
  list of files in a directory (depending on whether given path points
  to a file or a directory);
- the `jobs` and `kill` commands to control processes;
- a bunch of commands for manipulating files, such as `basename`,
  `chmod`, `chown`, `delete`, `dirname`, `rename`, `stat`, and `symlink`;
- a number of `File` methods’ synonyms: `directory?`, `executable?`,
  `exists?`, `readable?`, etc.;
- the equivalents to the `FileTest` class methods: `syscopy`, `copy`,
  `move`, `compare`, `safe_unlink`, `makedirs`, and `install`.

Comment: "There is no shell behind it to store environment changes between its calls"... yes there is. That's why the state is maintained between two commands (updated the question to demonstrate this). But how do I keep state "after your Ruby script is terminated"? Thanks.

Comment: 1.8.7, but Darwin (OSX). Just confirmed that this is different from Ubuntu, at least. However, on Linux you can do "system 'cd ..'" and that works.

Comment: Sorry, it returns false on Ubuntu. On Mac it returns true.

Comment: I've added an explanation of the "current directory" concept on Linux systems in the answer (the second paragraph).  So, at least on Linux, you cannot affect current directory of a parent process (relative to your script).

Comment: It looks like `system` call in Ruby is implemented differently on Linux and Mac OS X.  As far as I know (I'm using Linux most of the time), current directory is per-process based not only on Linux, but on Unix-like systems.

Comment: Thank @ib, so you're saying that there is no way for a script -- even a shell script -- to affect your current dir? Not even with export PWD or something?

Comment: Yes.  Child process (i.e. shell running a script) just cannot affect other processes' "current directory" path (including its parent process).  The only "trick" would be to change your scripts so that to run the chunk of a code that cd's somewhere, inside _the same_ (parent) process.  For example, if you have a Bash script `a.sh` that cd's to `/tmp`, running `a.sh` from the current shell would not affect current directory, but `source a.sh` would cause not to execute `a.sh` independently, but to run commands stored in `a.sh` in the current shell, in place.

Comment: @ib, in fact, I did that in my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ib, thanks, didn't notice the trick in your answer. Nice stuff, I'll delete mine and mark yours as best answer. Sorry to put you through all this work :)

Comment: Ugh, this ` | source /dev/stdin` doesn't work on OSX. It doesn't error, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then you could try `source <(ruby prepare_and_print_commands.rb)`.  That's because some shells runs sub-process to source file and `/dev/stdin` is changed during that process.  Both variants works on Linux (tried Zsh and Bash).

Comment: By the way, what shell do you use to run `source ...`?  (I'm asking because some archaic shells like `sh` might not work with such source redirection.)